# Is it inappropriate for a woman to medically prevent her menses?

Tags: women, medical, human-body, menses

There's medical methods of preventing menses, see e.g., [Stop Your Periods With Continuous Birth Control](https://www.webmd.com/sex/birth-control/features/no-more-periods):

> **The Pill**
>   In most cases, you take pills with hormones for 21 days. Then, for 7 days, you take those that don’t have hormones. For many women, it’s safe to skip the ones without the hormones -- and skip your period.

I'm wondering if this is considered an appropriate type of medicine, of if it's considered a kind of tampering (along the lines of [Qur'an 4:119](https://quran.com/4/119)).

**Question**: Is it inappropriate for a woman to medically prevent her menses?